# When one need to use archives.php page

Tags: wordpress, archive

Why do I need this page in my wordpress theme? What url can cause wordpress to use archives.php? If I delete this page from my theme, what will happen?

Thanks in advance for any specific reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will happen if your theme is properly structured. Basically all needed files in your theme are `style.css, functions.php and index.php`.

You can do all your logic in index.php, but оne of the main advantages of WordPress is template hierarchy [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), part of which is `archive.php`

WordPress searches down through the template hierarchy until it finds a matching template file. So you can catch this query at any point in this hierarchy and be more flexible in your theme.

[Another hierarchy useful resource](http://wphierarchy.com/)